# convert a list of list to a list of string (or float)

Tags: python, string, list, join

I have this:

```
[[['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0.0178885743420442']], [['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0.00189664199330356'], ['0.0105739740488949']], [['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0.0131745569045574']]]
```

Finally, i want to get:

```
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0178885743420442'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0.00189664199330356', '0.0105739740488949'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0131745569045574']]
```

I tried to use join but nothing happend
thanks

Comment: Can you show what you have done?

Comment: You are looking to flatten the list and there are many example on SO of flattening, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python

Comment: No, there is an error message: sequence item 0: expected string, list found

Comment: `join` will only work on a iterable containing strings. It wont work on an iterable containing lists. It's basically a string concatenation function.

Comment: @MeiOlya, you posted a different input and output originally. After a solution was posted, you edited the entire input and output invalidating all the posted solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*mylist))
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0216939116219239', '0.44748960163182', '1.47290267132899', '2.34321826311047', '2.99520324761532', '3.11538509056595', '3.46600327678834', '2.80910123913849']
```

Comment: Before anyone downvotes this answer: The person asked a different question initially and this answer was for that question. Now the question itself is changed and this answer will not answer the new question.

Answer (score 2):

Simply do a list comprehension:

```
x = [['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0.0216939116219239'], ['0.44748960163182'], ['1.47290267132899'], ['2.34321826311047'], ['2.99520324761532'], ['3.11538509056595'], ['3.46600327678834'], ['2.80910123913849']]
print [j for i in x for j in i]
```

Output:

```
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0216939116219239', '0.44748960163182', '1.47290267132899', '2.34321826311047', '2.99520324761532', '3.11538509056595', '3.46600327678834', '2.80910123913849']
```

Or

```
print [ast.literal_eval(j) for i in x for j in i]  # for list of floats and integers
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0216939116219239, 0.44748960163182, 1.47290267132899, 2.34321826311047, 2.99520324761532, 3.11538509056595, 3.46600327678834, 2.80910123913849]
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what is "ast.literal_eval(j)

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` safely evaluates a python expression (literal), and is useful for turning a string into a native type, e.g. `ast.literal_eval('0')` will return an `int`, where as `ast.literal_eval('0.0216939116219239')` will return a `float`.

Comment: @MeiOlya see above comment

Answer (score 0):

this would work (picks up first element of every sub-list):

```
[x[0] for x in list]
```

Comment: I have in reality a list like this: 

[[['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0.0178885743420442']], [['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0.00189664199330356'], ['0.0105739740488949']], [['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0.0131745569045574']]]

Using a loop for, I can't made it with your proposition, isn't it ?

Comment: `>>> [x[0] for y in list for x in y]`

Comment: I want to have [['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0178885743420442'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0.00189664199330356', '0.0105739740488949'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0131745569045574']] but with your code all lists are gone

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Python list comprehension combined with the [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) function from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) as follows:

```
from itertools import chain

data = [[['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0.0178885743420442']], [['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0.00189664199330356'], ['0.0105739740488949']], [['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0.0131745569045574']]]

output = [list(chain.from_iterable(x)) for x in data]
print output
```

The combines each of the sub-sub-entries into sub-entries.

Giving you the desired output as follows:

```
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0178885743420442'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0.00189664199330356', '0.0105739740488949'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0131745569045574']]
```